# Adjust Apache reverse proxy to use OAuth2 Google sign-in in a Spring Boot application deployed in a Tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, google-oauth, reverse-proxy, google-signin

I have a Spring Boot application which uses Google Oauth2 Sign-in implementation. The application is deployed on a Tomcat listening on port 8080. In front of the Tomcat, an Apache is used as a reverse proxy to direct the incoming requests to the Tomcat. The file 000-default-le-ssl.conf of the Apache contains the following vhost code:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ServerName minidrive.gr

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/minidrive/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/minidrive/

        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443

        <Location "/minidrive">
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The application.properties of the Spring Boot application contains the following code:

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol_header=x-forwarded-proto
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=blabla-client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=blabla-secret
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

However, the whole process is not working. Starting from redirect_uri, Spring adds the baseUrl (minidrive) at the beginning, which I don't want, since I want the application to be accessible at /.

By setting hard-coded redirect_uri, I get past this stage, but I have a problem right after the user consent, i.e. authentication fails. I suspect that in the background, Spring adds the baseUrl again, and that is why the user is not authenticated.

Authentication is successfully performed if I try the same procedure using the Tomcat URI and port 8080.

Would you happen to have any suggestions about this?